# What alternatives are there to using Indy for making an internet connection with Delphi?

Tags: software-development

I need to make a connection between an old program made with Delphi 2007 and a new Android app that I'll build with XE7.

It should be able to send TStream, but other than that I don't have other requirements.

Comment: Just curious, are you saying that Indy can't do that?  I never tried, but take a look at https://github.com/Fr0sT-Brutal/awesome-delphi#network  - and don't forget Project Jedi http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/

Comment: It should be able to do it in theory, but I'm having a lot of trouble with it.